# Android; xamarin: LayoutParams are beeing ignored...?

Tags: android, xamarin

I've got a bit of a problem here ( as you could probably figure... :D)

This is the code in question:

```
    var imageView = new ImageView(context);

    param = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MatchParent, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MatchParent);
    imageView.LayoutParameters = param; 

    imageView.SetImageResource(treeCatalog[position].imageId);

    var viewPager = container.JavaCast<ViewPager>();
    viewPager.AddView(imageView, param);
    return imageView;
```

So, as you can see, I have an imageView, that I need to adjust programatically. I then set LayoutParams and handed them over (2x!) to the ImageView. However, no matter how I set them - nothing happens. The ImageView still is the same as before. This is driving my crazy.

Any help?

THANKS!

Comment: Your description and code make no sense....

Answer (score 0):

Based on your code `viewPager.AddView(imageView, param);`, you want to add image to your `ViewPager`, then the `LayoutParams` should be [ViewPager.LayoutParams](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.LayoutParams.html), which should be supplied for views added to a `ViewPager`.

**But** I don't think set the `LayoutParams` of `ImageView` here should fix your problem, I guess that you want to fill the whole item of `ViewPager` with image. Then you need to stretch the image.

So, you can try to change your code like this:

```
var imageView = new ImageView(context);
imageView.SetImageResource(treeCatalog[position].imageId);

imageView.SetScaleType(ScaleType.FitXy);

// Add the image to the ViewPager:
var viewPager = container.JavaCast<ViewPager>();
viewPager.AddView(imageView);
return imageView;
```